# Iterate xml values(wikimapia)

Tags: php, xml, iteration

I am trying to fetch some data off the wikimapia website by implementing their API. When I try to iterate through the values, it iterates the "id" values only.
Please see my PHP code below for getting the data:

```
<?php

$url = ("http://api.wikimapia.org/?function=search&key=****&q=buildings&lat=51.5424&lon=-0.1734&count=20&page=1");

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($xml->place as $entry) {

echo $entry->attributes()->id;
echo $entry->attributes()->name;
echo $entry->attributes()->url;
echo $entry->attributes()->lat;
echo $entry->attributes()->lon;

}
// Process XML file

?>
```

Find below an excerpt of the XML structure from the website:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?access-control allow="*"?>
<folder language="en" version="1.0" found="87" page="1" count="20">
<place id="18508464">
<name>Miles Buildings</name>
<url>http://wikimapia.org/18508464/Miles-Buildings</url>
<location>
<lon>-0.1703605</lon>
<lat>51.5211928</lat>
<north>51.5218053</north>
<south>51.5205803</south>
<east>-0.1696712</east>
<west>-0.1710498</west>
</location>
<polygon>
<point x="-0.1699769" y="51.5218053"/>
<point x="-0.1696712" y="51.5214648"/>
<point x="-0.1703846" y="51.5211177"/>
<point x="-0.1699823" y="51.5206971"/>
<point x="-0.1703203" y="51.5205803"/>
<point x="-0.1708031" y="51.5209341"/>
<point x="-0.1707333" y="51.5209741"/>
<point x="-0.1710498" y="51.5212812"/>
</polygon>
</place>
</folder>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

folder attributes are:

```
language="en" version="1.0" found="87" page="1" count="20"
```

The other are child nodes, try to use `print_r($xml);` to see what you get

Comment: What is the output? you must see the object and nodes as `[]`

Comment: what i meant is that you add `print_r($xml);` to your script and see what it prints